# how do I avoid getting double array in serializer django?

Tags: python, django, api

I am trying to return all of the references for all of the books associated with the author, but however, I am getting an array inside array where I know its because `foo` in serializer, and `ArrayField(models.URLField()` , but I want to return as a string instead of an array of arrays.

note: the API consume as a read-only so doesn't matter writeable fields

```
class Books(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class References(models.Model):
    bookid = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    references = ArrayField(models.URLField(),null=True, blank=True, default=list)


serializer

class ReferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = References
        fields = ("references",)


class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ('id','summary','foo', 'last_modified',)

    def get_foo(self, value):
        items = References.objects.filter(bookid=value)
        serializer = ReferenceSerializer(instance=items, many=True)
        return serializer.data

viewset

class BooksViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Books.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        search = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)
        if search is not None:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(
                Q(summary__icontains=search) | Q(id__iexact=search)
            )
        return self.queryset
```

response

```
{
   "count":1,
   "next":null,
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
      {
         "id":"2021-3420",
         "summary":"",
         "foo":[
            [
               "www.google.com",
               "gksjksjs.com"
            ]
         ],
         "last_modified":"2021-03-06T00:41:00Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is simply that an instance of `Books` can be related to multiple instances of `References` as `References` has a `ForeignKey` to `Books`. This might be a model design problem of yours either change the Foreign Key to a One to One field or change the `ArrayField` to be simply a `URLField`.

Comment: each books has multiples references . that's why ArrayField(url)

Comment: `References` having a `ForeignKey` to `Books` already implies a Many-to-One relationship. In that you still put an array for multiple values. Understand the point now?

Comment: exactly, many-to-one, but I want to avoid getting array [ array[] ]

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `values_list` method of the querysets. `flat=True` will do the job.

**Note:** If you want to serialize more than one field, unfortunately **flat=True** option is not the case. But from your example it seems you want to use only one **"references"** field.

**Note 2:** Itertools is a really fast and elegant approach for such cases. As a next step, you can make your result become flatten.

```
import itertools
    
def get_foo(self, value):
    qs = list(References.objects.values_list("references", flat=True)) 
    qs_flat = list(itertools.chain(*qs))
    return qs_flat
```

Comment: the problem is `"foo":[["www.google.com","gksjksjs.com"]]` when I want `"foo":["www.google.com","gksjksjs.com"]`

Comment: @anaosuna I have updated the answer. Itertools will help for the next step.

Answer (score 0):

just return the first element instead of returning full serializer data.

```
def get_foo(self, value):
    items = References.objects.filter(bookid=value)
    serializer = ReferenceSerializer(instance=items, many=True)
    return serializer.data[0] if serializer.data else ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `to_representation` method of `BooksSerializer` to get the desired output.

```
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:...
        
    def get_foo(self, value):...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        serialized_instance = super().to_representation(instance)
        serialized_instance['foo'] = ' '.join(serialized_instance['foo'][0])
        return serialized_instance
```

Comment: the problem is "foo":[["www.google.com","gksjksjs.com"]] when I want "foo":["www.google.com","gksjksjs.com"]

Comment: @anaosuna check out my other answer.

Comment: @VishalSingh probably you should delete one of your answers and update one with other's content.

Comment: @ruddra It wasn't clear what op needed that's why I added the other answer. I'll delete one of them as soon as op gives me acknowledgment.